# .net string comparison with collation

Tags: c#, utf-8, collation, string-comparison

I have 2 different strings (`XXÈ` and `XXE`). Is there any way to compare them using a collation (for this case, it would be `UTF8 general CI` - I need them to be equal)? I've seen few examples involving MSSQL or SQLLite - but this would add an unnecessary dependency to my project. So, my question is - is there any way to do this in pure .net (especially c#)?

**Update:**

Let's take any decent SQL engine as an example. You can create a table and you can select the collation for the table. In our case, `XXÈ` and `XXE` will be stored in the table, they will have different binary representations (depending on the encoding), but when you search for `XXE`, it will match also `XXÈ`.

My case is pretty much similar. I have a text file with some strings in it (UTF8). I want to display the values on screen (sorted - where the collation is again, relatively important) and I want to let the user search for values. The collation used for search will be an option.

Comment: have a look at [Encoding class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Selman22 - thank you. afaik, encoding refers only to the way string is represented internally. I still need "E" to be visible as "E" and "È" to be "È", but when I write the code, i need "È" to be equal with "E". Something like SQL does (XXE will find XXÈ depending on the collation of the table);

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`String.Normalize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1(v=vs.110).aspx) and a little bit LINQ-power:

```
string initial = "XXÈ";
string normal = initial.Normalize(NormalizationForm.FormD);

var withoutDiacritics = normal.Where(
    c => CharUnicodeInfo.GetUnicodeCategory(c) != UnicodeCategory.NonSpacingMark);
string final = new string(withoutDiacritics.ToArray());
bool equals = "XXE".Equals(final); // true
```

Reference: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RemoveDiacritics.aspx

Comment: I was thinking to something more automated. Without me having to manually cleanup the text from diacritics and other stuff. It is nearly impossible to do this to cover all languages/situations.

Comment: @dcg: i don't understand why it's impossible. You wanted an approach in C#, so put this in a method(or even a string-extension) with a meaningful name and use that instead of `==` or `Equals` where you need it.

Comment: Not entirely impossible. But how would I handle any chinese/japanese collation where some characters are visually somehow different even though they are pretty close as a meaning?