# How to print (Turkish) alphabet with C# and NCLDR?

Tags: c#, alphabetical, alphabet

CLDR is set of XML files, that contains character sets

NCLDR is library from https://github.com/GuySmithFerrier/NCLDR

here is the expected result with 29 letters - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turkish_alphabet

How to print these characters?

there are similar questions, but their comments only suggest various problems and no solutions.

Some of you will definitely say, that it is very simple homework task. If it is so, please go answer

[How to enumerate the LOCALIZED alphabet in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5676692/how-to-enumerate-the-localized-alphabet-in-c)

[Generating an array of letters in the alphabet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314466/generating-an-array-of-letters-in-the-alphabet-in-c-sharp)

[.net string comparison with collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26483814/net-string-comparison-with-collation)

[use a custom encoding or add custom characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386062/use-a-custom-encoding-or-add-custom-characters)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520088/the-right-way-to-use-custom-encoding-class-in-c-sharp

Comment: Do you have to use NCLDR or just because of printing Turkish alphabet you used it?

Comment: It is MIT licensed and I WANT to use it, because I see no alternative (except of nasty hacks and hardcoding). Also, mono is my platform.